# Deriving the Weibull Distribution using the Exponential

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

I need to derive the Weibull Distribution using the Exponential, I can see that the CDF's of the two are very similar.

The CDF of the exponential is:
$$
F(x) = 1-e^{(-x/b)^a}
$$

And the CDF of the Weibull is:
$$
F(x) = 1-e^{(-x.b)}
$$

Comment: You got it backwards.

Comment: So the transformation from exponential to weibull would be $X^{(a)}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we define the cumulative distribution function of the Weibull as:

$$F_{W}(x)=1-\exp\bigg(-\bigg(\frac{x}{\lambda}\bigg)^{k}\bigg)$$

and the cumulative distribution function of the standard exponential as:

$$F_{E}(x)=1-\exp(-x)$$

If we assume $X$ is a standard exponential random variable

$$X\sim \text{Exp}(1)$$

Then, by applying the transform

$$W=\lambda\, X^{1/k}$$

We can derive the relationship as:

$$\begin{align}
\text{Pr}(W\le x)&=\text{Pr}(\lambda \,X^{1/k}\le x)\\
&=\text{Pr}(X\le (x/\lambda)^k)\\
&=1-\exp\bigg(-\bigg(\frac{x}{\lambda}\bigg)^{k}\bigg)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for answering, quick question, isn't the CDF of the exponential: $$F_{E}(x)=1-\exp(-x\lambda)$$

Comment: @P.Math yes but I stated the *standard* exponential distribution, which is the case of $/lambda=1$.